Join tables with condition that all row values are unique
I have tables Machine and Inventory. In table Machine I have last running inventory properties. In table Inventory, I have new inventory id and properties (Not yet run in machine).
I have to return a list of possible combination inventory that can run in machines based on it last running inventory. And I also need to return list of machines with no duplicates inventory.
For list of possible combination inventory that can run in machines based on it last running inventory, I tried using CROSS JOIN and it works [Refer 1].
But for list of machines with no duplicates inventory I have no clue how to do it [Refer 2]?
Machine table - machine with last running inventory:



Machine
Inventory
Color
Size




A
1111
Red
Small


B
1112
Red
Small


C
1113
Green
Large



Inventory table - new inventory (not yet run in machines):



Inventory
Color
Size




1114
Red
Small


1115
Red
Small


1116
Green
Large



I need to get every combination (Machine CROSS JOIN Inventory where Color and Size matches)
SELECT 
    m.Machine, i.Inventory, m.Color, m.Size
FROM 
    Machine m
CROSS JOIN 
    Inventory i
WHERE 
    i.Color = m.Color AND i.Size = m.Size




Machine
Inventory
Color
Size




A
1114
Red
Small


A
1115
Red
Small


B
1114
Red
Small


B
1115
Red
Small


C
1116
Green
Large



I need to get no duplicate inventory (1 Machine, 1 Inventory)



Machine
Inventory
Color
Size




A
1114
Red
Small


B
1115
Red
Small


C
1116
Green
Large



For [2] I tried to do in the code, loop the machines and find 1 by 1 based on the color and size in Inventory table and assign.
Then exclude the one I already assign for the next machine.
But it took some time to iterate all.

@DaleK I added the query in the question

In your expected result, why does A have 114 and not 115 ? and why does B have 115 and not 114 ? What is exact the logic ?

@GuidoG there is no fixed logic, if 114 is assigned to A then 115 should be assign to B. Vice versa.

Looks like what you want is not really every combination but just assignment of 1 machine to 1 inventory.
You can use row_number() to generate the sequence number and then use that to join.
select m.machine, i.inventory
from   (
           select machine, color, size, 
                  rn = row_number() over (partition by color, size 
                                              order by machine)
           from   Machine
       ) m
       inner join
       (
           select inventory, color, size, 
                  rn = row_number() over (partition by color, size 
                                              order by inventory)
           from   Inventory
       ) i  on  m.color = i.color 
            and m.size  = i.size
            and m.rn    = i.rn

GuidoG has kindly provided a demo fiddle

Since I had already made a fiddle, I put your query into it, here you can see it working, I cannot think of a beter answer

Thanks @GuidoG, I will edit and include that fiddle in the answer.
